# how to host static website with cognito and s3 only

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have a bunch of html/css/js files. I have one index.html file. I would like to create some predefined users in cognito so that they can browse my website in s3. I don't want to create a login page by myself. I want only s3 and cognito, nothing else. is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to do a lot of your coding to achieve something like this. You can use the inbuilt cognito GUI to take care of registration and login but after that you need to write some code to use the generated tokens to grant user access to s3 hosted resorces which you will have to fetch and show on a webpage. 
So, no you cannot do this simply with s3 and cognito.